# Mostrar dos variables iguales en printf() sin hacer ninguna operación

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    int h,m;
    printf("ingresa la hora: ");
    scanf("%d", &h);
    printf("ingresa los minutos: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("hora introducida, okey.\n Son las() ");//aquí es la duda como los imprimo ambos//
    

    return 0;
}
```

Una vez declaradas

Título

Comment: Hola Emma, te damos la bienvenida, Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla! Cuando respondas un comentario, escribe "@nombreDelQueComento", para que este sea notificado.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. En este caso parece que Héctor pudo adivinar. Pero la pregunta no es clara .

Answer (score 1):

`printf` te permite pasarle una lista de argumentos e incluirlos en la cadena formateada.

Mira la función `printf` de esta forma:

```
printf(cadena, lista_de_argumentos)
```

Donde puedes hacer:

```
printf("hora introducida, okey.\n Son las(%d, %d)", h, m);
```

El `%d` en la primera posición será el primer argumento `h`, el `%d` en la segunda posición será el segundo argumento `m` y así sucesivamente. Aquí no debes colocar `&` antes de los nombres de las variables, ya que solo estás leyendo su valor.

En [esta entrada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34598089/how-can-you-print-multiple-variables-inside-a-string-using-printf) de Stack Overflow se muestran algunos ejemplos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias me ayudó bastante